# Outlook form region right to left

Tags: localization, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, right-to-left, outlook-form

I have created an Outlook add in that has a form region for Outlook 2007. The form region contains the sent, cc and bcc labels (OlkLabel), and some more stuff. 
This form should support right to left clients, meaning whoever uses Outlook in RTL languages such as Hebrew or Arabic.
However, when I open an email I get the "Sent: " label backwards, meaning

:Sent    (--> actually Sent stands for Hebrew/Arabic letters)
like

נשלח:

But the point is that the colon are misplaced. Meaning Outlook automatically aligns the textboxes and labels to the right, but the text inside is still left to right.

I didn't find any property of the label, like other program languages have.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks :)

Nili

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason why it happens is, that Unicode directionality algorithm decided to put the colon in this place. Usually adding space character after colon helps. If it is not resolving your issue, try using some strong directionality mark (like U+200F Right-to-Left-Mark or U+202E Right-to-Left-Override‎‎‎‎‎‎).
You could find them in Character Map by selecting advanced view, the last item from "Group by" drop-down and then "Standard punctuation characters" (or whatever it is on English OS, second item from the top in "Group by" pop-up window).

Comment: Thanks Pawel it worked beautifully, I added the character RTL in advance properties of the text box -> right click on the caption itself. Thanks! :)